# Xamarin Forms even sample apps now won't run

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

I'm starting out with mobile development and xamarin forms and am having a lot of issues. I was initially getting a lot of errors starting even sample apps, and I've gradually got to a point where I'm getting this as I start my emulator:

```
 3>Emulator Android_Accelerated_Nougat cannot be started (adb cannot initialize device).
 ========== Build: 2 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
 ========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and a Nougat emulator (Android 7.1 API 25).

Comment: Looks more like an evironment issue than anything else. See if you can pull up the device logs in the output pane to see the real reason why the emulator can't start. Also the stock emulators tend to suck. You might want to look into Genymotion (fun zone).

Comment: Please post a [diagnostic build output](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/troubleshooting/#Diagnostic_MSBuild_Output).

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, it should work out of the box. My proposition to you would be to re-install Xamarin plugin. But at first you can try with a different emulator. For example a good one - https://www.genymotion.com/

But I have doubts that it would work, since there should not be errors that you need to fix to run a demo project, and that means that maybe your emulator is not the problem.